# How to make mongodb listen on specific IP in Azure VM with Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: mongodb, azure, ubuntu

I got the MongoDB (4.0.10) running on Azure VM with Ubuntu 18.04 using default localhost. Now, I want to add my IP address to bindIp in /etc/mongod.conf so that I can access the db from my machine. Based on document (also from [this example](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)), I just need to append it to bindIp line after a comma.

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,70.123.39.234
  ipv6: true
```

(Note, I added ipv6 based on my reading of the document, but it doesn't seem to have any effect).

However, it doesn't work for me because service fails to start. I got something like this:

```
$ sudo service mongod restart 
$ sudo service mongod status
    ● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-06-10 15:59:35 UTC; 2s ago
         Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
      Process: 8140 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --auth --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=48)
     Main PID: 8140 (code=exited, status=48)

    Jun 10 15:59:35 mllinux systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
    Jun 10 15:59:35 mllinux systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=48/n/a
    Jun 10 15:59:35 mllinux systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I tried many ways like

```
bindIp: 127.0.0.1, 70.123.39.234
or
bindIp: "127.0.0.1,70.123.39.234"
or
bindIp: "127.0.0.1, 70.123.39.234"
```

I got the same error.

However if I use space instead of comma like

```
bindIp: 127.0.0.1 70.123.39.234
or
bindIp: "127.0.0.1 70.123.39.234"
```

Service seems to start ok because

```
$ sudo service mongod restart
$ sudo service mongod status
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-06-10 16:37:39 UTC; 3s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
 Main PID: 14629 (mongod)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
           └─14629 /usr/bin/mongod --auth --config /etc/mongod.conf

Jun 10 16:37:39 mllinux systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
```

However, I still cannot connect to it from my laptop.

For testing, if I set

```
bindIp: 0.0.0.0
or
bindIpAll: true
```

Then, I can connect to it from my laptop.

What did I do wrong?

UPDATE: Appending db log

```
2019-06-10T02:52:27.682+0000 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2019-06-10T02:52:27.684+0000 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2019-06-10T02:52:27.697+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3757 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=mllinux
2019-06-10T02:52:27.697+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.10
2019-06-10T02:52:27.697+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: c389e7f69f637f7a1ac3cc9fae843b635f20b766
2019-06-10T02:52:27.697+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
2019-06-10T02:52:27.697+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2019-06-10T02:52:27.697+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-06-10T02:52:27.697+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-06-10T02:52:27.697+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
2019-06-10T02:52:27.697+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-06-10T02:52:27.697+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-06-10T02:52:27.697+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1,70.123.39.234", port: 27017 }, processManagement: { timeZoneInfo: "/usr/share/zoneinfo" }, security: { authorizatio$2019-06-10T02:52:27.697+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Cannot assign requested address
2019-06-10T02:52:27.697+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2019-06-10T02:52:27.697+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:48


2019-06-10T02:53:53.313+0000 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2019-06-10T02:53:53.315+0000 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2019-06-10T02:53:53.324+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3934 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=mllinux
2019-06-10T02:53:53.324+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.10
2019-06-10T02:53:53.324+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: c389e7f69f637f7a1ac3cc9fae843b635f20b766
2019-06-10T02:53:53.324+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
2019-06-10T02:53:53.324+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2019-06-10T02:53:53.324+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-06-10T02:53:53.324+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-06-10T02:53:53.324+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
2019-06-10T02:53:53.324+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-06-10T02:53:53.324+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-06-10T02:53:53.324+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1 70.123.39.234", port: 27017 }, processManagement: { timeZoneInfo: "/usr/share/zoneinfo" }, security: { authorizatio$2019-06-10T02:53:53.325+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/lib/mongodb created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2019-06-10T02:53:53.325+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
2019-06-10T02:53:53.325+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2019-06-10T02:53:53.325+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2019-06-10T02:53:53.325+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1448M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=jou$2019-06-10T02:53:54.146+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1560135234:146511][3934:0x7fe345319a40], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 2/6656 to 3/256
2019-06-10T02:53:54.249+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1560135234:249632][3934:0x7fe345319a40], txn-recover: Recovering log 2 through 3
2019-06-10T02:53:54.317+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1560135234:317186][3934:0x7fe345319a40], txn-recover: Recovering log 3 through 3
2019-06-10T02:53:54.366+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1560135234:366900][3934:0x7fe345319a40], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
2019-06-10T02:53:54.485+0000 I RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
2019-06-10T02:53:54.504+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-06-10T02:53:54.504+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2019-06-10T02:53:54.504+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2019-06-10T02:53:54.504+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-06-10T02:53:54.515+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/var/lib/mongodb/diagnostic.data'
2019-06-10T02:53:54.517+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2019-06-10T02:56:27.392+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
2019-06-10T02:56:27.392+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2019-06-10T02:56:27.392+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2019-06-10T02:56:27.395+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down free monitoring
2019-06-10T02:56:27.395+0000 I FTDC     [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture
2019-06-10T02:56:27.397+0000 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2019-06-10T02:56:27.397+0000 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down session sweeper thread
2019-06-10T02:56:27.397+0000 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] Finished shutting down session sweeper thread
2019-06-10T02:56:27.558+0000 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2019-06-10T02:56:27.558+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2019-06-10T02:56:27.558+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] shutting down with code:0
```

Comment: Please update the error message from /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log (default Path) .

Comment: @Mani I included two relevant error messages above. Thank you very much!

Comment: Nothing help with my answer? Or give the update.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `bindip` to limit access from the outside to the mongodb. `bindip` selects the desired server listen IPs, not the client IPs.

If you only want to be able to connect to the server from your IP address, you should use the [Network Security Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/security-center-restrict-access-through-internet-facing-endpoints) feature of Azure. It is more secure than handling it via the software installed on the VM, since traffic does not even reach the VM.

Comment: Are you suggesting to set bindIpAll to true (Isn't this a bad idea in general?) and then setup a inbound security role in VM to allow my ip for 27017 only? So I misunderstood it completely? But I read "Open MongoDB Port in UFW" in https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ again and it does sound like that's what I expected.

Comment: Yes that is what I suggest. Or use the public IP of the VM, but that might change depending on your setup. It is a bad idea to open all unless you secured access from the outside. That is what the security group is for. The sample you mention uses 192.168.1.10 as the external ip (your laptop) and 192.168.1.100 as the server up (azure VM)

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, you should know what does the three IPs mean and then you will know what you need to do as you wish.

**First one: 127.0.0.1**

This IP is just for the test inside the machine, it cannot access outside. It's just a loop IP.

**Second one: 0.0.0.0**

Then this IP is set, then you can access outside and also can access inside. It means the localhost for all the application in this machine, no matter inside or outside.

**Third one: private IP**

This is the IP assigned in your private network, not the public IP. For example, it means the IP 192.168.1.100 in the document you provide. And for the Azure VM, it means the private IP assigned from the subnet. But it only works when you access this IP.

So, in your question, if you want to access both outside and inside. Then you can set the bind IP in the simplest way:

1. 0.0.0.0
2. private IP

Note: do not forget to expose the port in the NSG associated with your Azure VM. If you do not have a special requirement, I will suggest you bind the IP 0.0.0.0, it's the best way.